# Find elements NOT in the intersection of two lists

Tags: python

So I know how to find the intersection of two lists by doing:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,5,6]
>>> list(set(a) & set(b))
[1, 3, 5]
```

But what is the best way to find all the elements that are not included in the intersection. My initial idea is to create a union of the two lists and then remove all the elements from the intersection from the union, as such:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,5,6]
>>> intersection = list(set(a) & set(b))
>>> union = list(set(a) | set(b))
>>> non_intersection = intersection - union
[2, 4, 6]
```

Is this the best way to do this or is there another way?

Comment: What you're looking for is called the symmetric difference.  Sets have a method for it.  Try googling.

Comment: To add on what BrenBarn said, use `^` instead of `&`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I usually prefer a shortcut:

```
set(a) ^ set(b)
{2, 4, 6}
```

Comment: hi, out of interest what is the idea with the "^"?

Comment: @JeJe The `^` operator in this case is similar to the "XOR" operator for bitwise functions, but for set mathematics. Here it is finding the symmetric difference between two sets, returning a new set composed of only the items that are included in set A or set B, but not both.

Answer (score 20):

Symmetric difference?

```
>>> set(a).symmetric_difference(b)
{2, 4, 6}
```

Comment: `symmetric_difference` takes in any iterable, so there's no need for the second call to `set`.

Comment: ty! This is ANOTHER reason for preferring the method over the shortcut 
The other being: its much more explicit!
btw: Looots of these take any iterable!

Comment: can this method be used for two pd df and extract non intersecting rows

Comment: `symmetric_difference` doesn't work on iterable list.