# How to find if a certain element is not present in either of the lists in python

Tags: python

I have 2 lists

```
lis1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1]
lis2=[4,5,8,7,10,6,9,8]
```

I want to write a function that can return elements that are present in either `lis1` or `lis2` the output should be `[1,2,3,7,8,9,10]` since 1,2,3 are not present in lis2 and 7,8,9,10 are not present in lis1

Comment: you can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185258/find-elements-not-in-the-intersection-of-two-lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find non-common elements in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348347/find-non-common-elements-in-lists)

Comment: @Sanchit.Jain Thank You

Comment: @RajuKomati Yes it does

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need ordered result, try this:

```py
lis1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 1]
lis2 = [4, 5, 8, 7, 10, 6, 9, 8]

set1 = set(lis1)
set2 = set(lis2)

print(set1 ^ set2)  # XOR operation for two sets
```

output:

```py
{1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get an ordered result:

`lis1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,1]
lis2=[4,5,8,7,10,6,9,8]`

`y=11` put in y maximum number you want to check

`for x in range(1, y):
    if x not in lis1 and x in lis2:
        print(x)
    if x not in lis2 and x in lis1:
        print(x)`