# How to maintain order when finding symmetric difference between two list in Python?

Tags: python, list, set

Given two lists, the objective is to find the non-overlapping value between them.

Based on the suggestion discussed in [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40185258/6446053). This can be achieved either of the two approach

```
list_one=['ISL','BUK','ORG','CLC','STS','PLP','t1','t2','t3','t4','DE1','DE2','DE4']
list_two=['t1','t2','t3','t4']

APP1=set(list_one) ^ set(list_two)

APP2 = set(list_one).symmetric_difference(list_two)
```

Both suggestion outputted

```
{'DE4', 'DE2', 'CLC', 'STS', 'ORG', 'BUK', 'ISL', 'DE1', 'PLP'}
```

While this work, but the order from `list_one` is distorted.
My question is, how can the above code be modified to output as below, where, the ordering follow as per in `list_one`

```
EXPECTED_OUTPUT=['ISL','BUK','ORG','CLC','STS','PLP','DE1','DE2','DE4']
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess that isn't a proper duplicate. But maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
inner_set = set(list_one) & set(list_two)
EXPECTED_OUTPUT = [i for i in list_one + list_two if i not in inner_set]

# or
EXPECTED_OUTPUT = [i for i in list_one + list_two if not (i in list_one and i in list_two)]
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the question, recheck it