# PySpark - Filter dataframe columns based on list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with some column names and I want to filter out some columns based on a list.

I have a list of columns I would like to have in my final dataframe:

`final_columns = ['A','C','E']`

My dataframe is this:

```
data1 = [("James",  "Lee", "Smith","36636"),
         ("Michael","Rose","Boots","40288")]

schema1 = StructType([StructField("A",StringType(),True),    
                      StructField("B",StringType(),True),    
                      StructField("C",StringType(),True),    
                      StructField("D",StringType(),True)])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema1)
```

I would like to transform df1 in order to have the columns of this final_columns  list.

So, basically, I expect the resulting dataframe to look like this

```
+--------+------+------+ 
|      A |    C |    E | 
+--------+------+------+ 
|  James |Smith |      | 
|Michael |Boots |      | 
+--------+------+------+
```

Is there any smart way to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If a column in final_columns is not in your df, you want it added with nulls?

Comment: Yes, If a column in final_columns is not in the df, then it can be added with nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with `select` and a list comprehension. The idea is to loop through `final_columns`, if a column is in `df.colums` then add it, if its not then use `lit` to add it with the proper alias.

You can write similar logic with a for loop if you find list comprehensions less readable.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df1.select([c if c in df1.columns else lit(None).alias(c) for c in final_columns]).show()

+-------+-----+----+                                                            
|      A|    C|   E|
+-------+-----+----+
|  James|Smith|null|
|Michael|Boots|null|
+-------+-----+----+
```

Comment: Agree to the loop approach. This does the job! THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome, if it answers your question you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:  use the DataFrame `drop()` method with a list which represents the [symmetric difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185258/find-elements-not-in-the-intersection-of-two-lists) between the DataFrame's current columns and your list of final columns.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 1, "1", 0.1),(1, 2, "1", 0.2),(3, 3, "3", 0.3)],('a','b','c','d'))

df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|  1|0.1|
|  1|  2|  1|0.2|
|  3|  3|  3|0.3|
+---+---+---+---+

# list of desired final columns
final_cols = ['a', 'c', 'd']

df2 = df.drop( *set(final_cols).symmetric_difference(df.columns) )
```

Note an alternate syntax for the symmetric difference operation:

```
df2 = df.drop( *(set(final_cols) ^ set(df.columns)) )
```

This gives me:

```
+---+---+---+
|  a|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1|0.1|
|  1|  1|0.2|
|  3|  3|0.3|
+---+---+---+
```

Which I believe is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this doesn't add the extra columns that are in final_cols but not in dataframe. If final_cols = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'] then the 'e' column won't appear

Comment: Gotcha.  I'll leave my answer here in case it fills a need for someone else later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement have written a dynamic code. This will select columns based on the list provided and also create column with null values if that column is not present in the source/original dataframe.

```
data1 = [("James",  "Lee", "Smith","36636"),
         ("Michael","Rose","Boots","40288")]

schema1 = StructType([StructField("A",StringType(),True),    
                      StructField("B",StringType(),True),    
                      StructField("C",StringType(),True),    
                      StructField("D",StringType(),True)])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema1)
actual_columns = df1.schema.names
final_columns = ['A','C','E']


def Diff(li1, li2):
  diff = list(set(li2) - set(li1))
  return diff
def Same(li1, li2):
  same = list(sorted(set(li1).intersection(li2)))
  return same

df1 = df1.select(*Same(actual_columns,final_columns))
for i in Diff(actual_columns,final_columns):
  df1 = df1.withColumn(""+i+"",lit(''))
display(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this doesn't work if I add another item to final_columns. For example if final_columns = ['A','C','E','F']

Comment: i have modified my code to occupy your changes. For example if final_columns = ['A','C','E','F']